# Does Adaptive Cards supports Toast Notification

Tags: toast, adaptive-cards

Can we send Adaptive Cards as a Toast Notification to Action Center?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Assuming you are referring to Windows Notifications, no this is not supported today and has been put on hold to put energy into higher priority efforts. We hope to revisit this at some point.

Comment: Matt, Thank you very much for the clarification.